# Does adding //domain.com/jquery.js slow down the site?

Tags: css, seo, pagespeed

I am aware that for SSL, and non SSL connections, you can use the // double slash followed by domain name and file src within CSS and JavaScript and HTML. Examples:

```
<script src="//site.com/js.js"></script>
<img src="//site.com/pic.jpg" />
.div{background:url(//site.com/assets/bg.gif)}
```

Does this slow down the page - latency - does the browser or mobile device need to check this ever time?

Comment: What? Do you mean *"is using a protocol-relative URL slower than using an absolute URL"*?

Comment: yeah. please comment below to keep it consistant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine, and works excellently.... Except in two particular circumstances:

Firstly, in ie 7 & 8, if this approach is used with CSS, two copies are downloaded, one from HTTP one from HTTPS and one from HTTP - so you're wasting some bandwidth there (though it's not necessarily a bad thing if you send expires headers down the wire with the CSS)

Finally, if you are using a windows machine this path may trigger a lookup for a network path when working on your local machine - if you have experienced slowness using this approach, this is likely the cause.

Some discussion around this in this [article](http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/), Paul Irish makes a comment on the article about the second issue i outlined, and someone else discusses the first issue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: for additional clarity, when I talk about using this approach for CSS I mean using the `<link>` tag to include a CSS file, not referencing an image from within CSS (as your example shows). I'm not sure what the behaviour is in the latter case

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering too.. what if you dont have any SSL cert on the server - would that not then bring a bad request up as the IE downloads are not downloading anything the first time round.

Comment: I'd guess that it would either just silently fail or issue a certificate error? However this is a non-issue because protocol-less URLs are only useful if you *do* have an SSL cert